# How can I pass command-line parameters with whitespace to an apache pig script?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to write a pig script that takes a filter condition as a command line parameter. From the command line I want to type something like:

```
pig -p "MY_FILTER=field1 == 0 and field2 == 5" myscript.pig
```

In my script I have a line:

```
my_filtered_data = filter my_data by $MY_FILTER;
```

This works as expected when `MY_FILTER` has no spaces *and* I pass quotes around my value; So if I type `MY_FILTER=\"field1==0\"` at the command line the shell will pass the quotes with the value and pig does the expansion I want. However, the parameter will fail to expand if I supply it like `MY_FILTER=\"field1 == 0\"`

I've tried a bunch of different quoting techniques and even tried running the command directly from python's subprocess module to ensure my shell wasn't doing something weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Pig do you use? I use 0.9.2 and the following command works for me:

```
 pig -p "F='field1 == 3 AND field2 == 5'" test.pig
```

But it doesn't work with 0.8.1.

Comment: I'm using 0.9.3, but it occurs to me that my commands are being passed through another level of shell interpretation before being called by Pig...I need to investigate more.

Comment: Yup. The shell script that calls pig is not doing proper quoting so the command line is not being passed through correctly.