# whitespace character in case of parameter substitution

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I want to pass a filter statement with in my pig script using parameter substitution

For that I have tried

```
    exec -param flt='a1==1 AND a2=2' filterscript.pig
```

But sadly it is throwing an exception message

```
    ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 101: Local file 'AND' does not exist.
```

Pig version - 0.9.2

I have tried `flt='\'a1==1 AND a2=2\''` and `flt="a1==1 AND a2==2"` suggested by pig users in apache forum as well as seen a similar post in SO.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the parameter passed as it is as a condition. If so you will get an error like this. Instead you can pass them as separate paarmeters and form the condition string inside the pig script.

```
exec -p p1=1 -p p2=2 filterscript.pig
```

Inside your filterscript.pig script you can use these parameter values in condition clauses. For example

```
a1==$p1 AND a2=$p2
```

Comment: thanks for the response. And yes that way i know. Seen something interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501537/how-can-i-pass-command-line-parameters-with-whitespace-to-an-apache-pig-script , That why trying that way. there were many JIRA issue raised for these category of problem and all are closed. According to them they are supporting this way of interpretation.

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting. So I think you should use -param "flt='a1==1 AND a2=2'". Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you run your script outside the grunt shell you can do the followings:

```
pig -param flt="a1\=\=1 AND a2\=\=2" -f filterscript.pig
```

where `filterscript.pig` is something like this:

```
A = load ...
...
B = filter A by $flt;
...
```

Note that the `'='` is also escaped, otherwise the filter condition won't be evalued to boolean.

If you want to use the filter substitution *within the grunt shell* as you tried with exec,
then you'll encounter the whitespace problem. Since escaping the whitespace character doesn't work, as a workaround you can create a [parameter file](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/cmds.html#exec) :

```
cat params.txt
flt="a1\=\=1 AND a2\=\=2"
```

Then issue:

```
exec -param_file params.txt filterscript.pig
```

Note: I use Pig 0.12

Comment: thanks for the response. i have tried it from outside the grunt shell,  its showing `ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Encountered unexpected arguments on command line - please check the command line`. I have run it in debug mode, output of the substituted file `f = filter p by a1 ;`, which means it is able to substitute till a1

Comment: if i just pass `flt="a1\=\=1" `, then the substituted file looks like `f= filter p by a1==1`

Comment: Could you please post the command you executed? I've just checked on version 0.9.2 too and it works.

Comment: `dse pig -r -p flt="a1\=\=1 AND a2\=\=2"  filterscript.pig`

Comment: it works with 0.9.2. I have seen that also, but unable to figure out where is the problem in my case

Comment: Since the solution I provided works on regular Pig distributions, I can only assume that there might be some issue with the
version/environment you use (e.g: DataStax bundle?)